# How to get newly added events information

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, event, update

I am using rest api's to get salesforce data in my ios application. I am getting events details once, after that how can I get the events details which are newly added to system or modified. Basically how Can i implement delta sync with salesforce based on timestamp or what ever.

Please any one let me know how to succeed in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just grab the most recent `modifiedDate` from your current list of events, then issue a new query `where modifieddate > :myLastModDate`.

Keep in mind you need to format your DateTime as an ISO 8601 string, e.g. 2011-02-25T18:24:31.000Z